# ¿Cómo hacer un lector de código QR que le dé al usuario la opción de ver un video, imagen o dibujo?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d

Quiero hacer un lector de código QR que le dé al usuario la opción de ver un video, imagen o dibujo de acuerdo con la base de datos. No sé si es realmente difícil de hacer o si alguien ya lo había intentado.
Me gustaría saber si hay un plugin para ayudar con eso, incluso si se paga. Debería funcionar Android.Estoy usando unity y c# y vuforia también.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor considera leer [ask], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato ya que es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: lo siento @Aprendiz

Comment: mejoraré mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Hola tenes algunas librerías en la tienda Nuget de visual studio, podes buscarlas e implementarlas con la doc oficial de la misma. Zxing es una libreria gratis y segun la plataforma que uses tiene sus variantes.
Espero que te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Podría hacer con Python o JS?

Comment: Fijate en la tienda Nuget, para que tipo de proyectos es compatible.

Comment: Que tienda?No lo sé

Comment: Tienda Nuget que tienes disponible dentro de Visual Studio, o puedes fijarte aqui -> https://www.nuget.org/

Comment: No te olvides de puntuar si te ayude.